# Seo 301 absolute url redirects, Prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, seo, prestashop

I am cleaning up some old stuff and I need to do some 301 redirects.

**For example:**

- I have following absolute url: http://mysite.dk/product.asp?product=371&sub=0&page=1
- That i need to redirect to:
  http://mysite.dk/category/test

I have tried with htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /product.asp?product=371&sub=0&page=1 /category/test
```

But above code will not work, It is showing the 404 page and ignoring the redirect I just made. Note please that product.asp does not exists as a file!

However if I use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /product.asp /category/test/
```

It works sort off, but now I can't do redirects, based on the query string for that specific file.

Any suggestions? Btw I am using Prestashop=)
Best, Simon

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=371&sub=0&page=1
RewriteRule ^product\.asp$ /category/test/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` in the target is to strip off existing query string.

Comment: I get your point. What would be a preferred way to solve this? Unfortunately I can't get your code to work. It shows 404 :/ Btw as I see your code you are rewriting and not redirecting, is that true? :)

Comment: Same rule works for me on my Apache. Do you have other rules also? If then make sure to keep this rule as very first rule.

Comment: @simond no it's not true. It's redirecting. That's what the `R=301` tells it do. Same as you used 301 in your previous attempt.

Answer (score 1):

> mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite.

from [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Just add the rules from @anubhava answer into Prestashop .htaccess and it will works. Better to do it before `# ~~start~~` line, you will see notice in the file.